# TypeError: res.send is not a function with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

everybody, I'm obtaining the following error:

```
TypeError: res.send is not a function
```

Why is this happening?

```
exports.obtainToken = () => {
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
    axios
    .post('***',{
    client_id: '***',
    client_secret:'***',
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    },
    config)
    .then(res => {
        result = res.data;
        console.log(res.data)
        res.send(res.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}
```

In this file, the import is:

```
const axios = require('axios');
```

I've not imported `express`. Is that the problem? How could I solve?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Axios does not handle responses to the client

Comment: You may want to Look to this Answer. Same Problem. [Same Problem on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73871444/why-am-i-am-getting-a-typeerror-res-send-is-not-a-function-with-axios-res-send)

Comment: Are you trying to use inside an express application ? res.send is for sending response from the server. the response in axios is used for receiving the response from the server. If you are using inside express, change the variable of res used in axios and see if works!